# allure report is not generating for protractor cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, allure

Unable to generate allure report using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumberjs-allure2-reporter) example

but it is not giving any response.

Comment: Please give the version of your protractor, cucumber

Comment: @cucumber-3.6.5 is the version using

Comment: not getting any clear explanation of allure report in protractor cucumber